# To add a license page to my installer using NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I added this command in **NSIS** script to add license page

```
; License page     
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE
```

but i getting this error

```
!insertmacro: macro "MUI_PAGE_LICENSE" requires 1 parameter(s), passed 0!
```

help me step step by process to add a license page to my installer thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the actual license to be displayed (text or rich text format)

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "path\to\myLicense.txt"
```

Comment: at first i gave this as a first parameter !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "path\to\myLicense.txt" then i gor open failed error. but now used as!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "path\to\myLicense.rtf" its working damn fine thanks @idleberg

Comment: But the fact is i found the rite way before seeing this answer any way no issues to do so...;)